# How to emit to everyone using a poller with Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So I'm using [Server.js](https://serverjs.io/documentation/router/#socket-) for a middleware application that polls data every few seconds and emits the data to all clients. The problem I'm running into is that a new set of pollers are being created for every new socket connection, with each of those pollers getting and emiting to all clients (way too much data). I only want one poller that emits to all, is there a way to do this with Server.js using Socket.IO?

```
const server = require('server')
const { get, post, socket } = require('server/router')

socket('connect', socket => {
    // New connection
    setInterval(() => getData(socket), 60000),
});

function getData(socket) {
    let sets = db.newSet()
    if (typeof socket != 'undefined') {
        socket.io.emit("set", sets);
    }
    return '';
}
```